# ElasticSearch: index document correctly and create correct search request

Tags: elasticsearch

I apologize for my silly question, but as always being a newbie to some new SW stack it is hard to find an exact answer quickly. So please help.

Question 1:
I have many documents of the following shape. Quite simple, description of a company and some products that a company offers. The question is how to post this document into elasticsearch(ES)? Because nested structures have some important sense, but ES does not eat it as is.

Question 2:
It is about search request itself. I need to search through all such documents looking for appropriate phrase in the field "description" and also looking for particular type of products.
For example, I need to find all companies with description which includes phrase "South Africa",  which offer fruits and in the same time offer only onions from vegetable category.
Field "description" is just text. When everything is under products is pre-defined known lists. There are can be many many different categories and names under categories.
What could be search request in such case?

```
{
  "description": "The best goods from Africa",
  "products": [
    {
      "category": "fruits",
      "name": [ "oranges", "cocos" ]
    },
    {
      "category": "vegetables",
      "name": [ "cabbage", "cucumbers", "onion" ]
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: "but ES does not eat it as is" - are you using a defined mapping, or dynamic mapping?

Comment: I'm running Elastic interface, where I just copy-paste JSONs mentioned above.
As result I see, the document has only 2 fields, "description" and "products" which contains nested information as, seems like, 1 string.

Comment: Have you tried [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) fields?